# Sorting 3 arrays by key in CUDA (using Thrust perhaps)

Tags: cuda, gpu, sorting, thrust

I have `3` arrays of the same size (more than `300.000` elements). One array of float numbers and two arrays of indices. So, for each number I have `2` IDs.

All the `3` arrays are already in GPU global memory. I want to sort all the numbers with theirs IDs accordingly.

Is there any way I can use Thrust library to do this task?  Is there any better way than Thrust library?

Of course, I prefer not to copy them to and from host memory a couple of times. By the way, they're arrays not vectors.

Thanks for your help in advance.

---

**Tentative solution**, but this is extremely slow. It takes almost `4` seconds and my array size is in order of `300000`

```
thrust::device_ptr<float> keys(afterSum);
thrust::device_ptr<int> vals0(d_index);
thrust::device_ptr<int> vals1(blockId); 

thrust::device_vector<int> sortedIndex(numElements);
thrust::device_vector<int> sortedBlockId(numElements);

thrust::counting_iterator<int> iter(0);
thrust::device_vector<int> indices(numElements);
thrust::copy(iter, iter + indices.size(), indices.begin()); 

thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys + numElements , indices.begin());    

thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), vals0, sortedIndex.begin());
thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), vals1, sortedBlockId.begin());

thrust::host_vector<int> h_sortedIndex=sortedIndex;
thrust::host_vector<int> h_sortedBlockId=sortedBlockId;
```

Answer (score 11):

Of course you can use Thrust.  First, you need to wrap your raw CUDA device pointers with `thrust::device_ptr`.  Assuming your float values are in the array `pkeys`, and the IDs are in the arrays `pvals0` and `pvals1`, and numElements is the length of the arrays, something like this should work:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>

cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

cudaEventRecord(start);

thrust::device_ptr<float> keys(pkeys);
thrust::device_ptr<int> vals0(pvals0);
thrust::device_ptr<int> vals1(pvals1);

// allocate space for the output
thrust::device_vector<int> sortedVals0(numElements);
thrust::device_vector<int> sortedVals1(numElements);

// initialize indices vector to [0,1,2,..]
thrust::counting_iterator<int> iter(0);
thrust::device_vector<int> indices(numElements);
thrust::copy(iter, iter + indices.size(), indices.begin());

// first sort the keys and indices by the keys
thrust::sort_by_key(keys.begin(), keys.end(), indices.begin());

// Now reorder the ID arrays using the sorted indices
thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), vals0.begin(), sortedVals0.begin());
thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), vals1.begin(), sortedVals1.begin());

cudaEventRecord(stop);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float milliseconds = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
printf("Took %f milliseconds for %d elements\n", milliseconds, numElements);
```

Comment: Thanks harrism. I used almost exact code. except I changed pkeys,pvals, numElements with mine. I get a lot of errors.I put them in the question part. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I found how to solve the problem but now it is extremely slow. What can I do about that?

Comment: Geforce GTX 580. CC=2.0. Let me tell you the other thing I did was copying all the data to Host and with a for-loop on CPU I made an array of struct. then I used Thrust::sort to sort the array of struct. This took around 0.5 seconds. But obviously this shouldnt be the best way, because I'm copying data back and force between host and device. and I also have a loop on CPU.

Comment: I added timing code to the above example.  Can you run it with timing code with cuda Events as shown and see how much GPU time there is?

Answer (score 3):

I have compared the two approaches proposed above, namely, that using `thrust::zip_iterator` and that using `thrust::gather`. I have tested them in the case of sorting two arrays by key or three arrays, as requested by the poster. In all the two cases, the approach using `thrust::gather` has shown to be faster.

**THE CASE OF `2` ARRAYS**

```
#include <time.h>       // --- time
#include <stdlib.h>     // --- srand, rand

#include <thrust\host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\sort.h>
#include <thrust\iterator\zip_iterator.h>

#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

//#define VERBOSE
//#define COMPACT

int main() {

    const int N = 1048576;
    //const int N = 10;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    // --- Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_code(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_x(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_y(N);

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {       
        // --- Generate random numbers between 0 and 9
        h_code[k] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        h_x[k] = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        h_y[k] = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
    }

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_code(h_code);

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_x(h_x);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_y(h_y);

#ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("Before\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) printf("code = %i; x = %f; y = %f\n", h_code[k], h_x[k], h_y[k]);
#endif

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
#ifdef COMPACT
    thrust::sort_by_key(d_code.begin(), d_code.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_x.begin(), d_y.begin())));
#else

    // --- Initialize indices vector to [0,1,2,..]
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> iter(0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> indices(N);
    thrust::copy(iter, iter + indices.size(), indices.begin());

    // --- First, sort the keys and indices by the keys
    thrust::sort_by_key(d_code.begin(), d_code.end(), indices.begin());

    // Now reorder the ID arrays using the sorted indices
    thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x.begin());
    thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), d_y.begin(), d_y.begin());
#endif

    printf("Timing GPU = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

#ifdef VERBOSE
    h_code = d_code;
    h_x = d_x;
    h_y = d_y;

    printf("After\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) printf("code = %i; x = %f; y = %f\n", h_code[k], h_x[k], h_y[k]);
#endif
}
```

**THE CASE OF `3` ARRAYS**

```
#include <time.h>       // --- time
#include <stdlib.h>     // --- srand, rand

#include <thrust\host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\sort.h>
#include <thrust\iterator\zip_iterator.h>

#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

//#define VERBOSE
//#define COMPACT

int main() {

    const int N = 1048576;
    //const int N = 10;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    // --- Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_code(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_x(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_y(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_z(N);

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        // --- Generate random numbers between 0 and 9
        h_code[k] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        h_x[k] = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        h_y[k] = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        h_z[k] = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
    }

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_code(h_code);

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_x(h_x);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_y(h_y);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_z(h_z);

#ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("Before\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) printf("code = %i; x = %f; y = %f\n", h_code[k], h_x[k], h_y[k]);
#endif

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
#ifdef COMPACT
    thrust::sort_by_key(d_code.begin(), d_code.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_x.begin(), d_y.begin(), d_z.begin())));
#else

    // --- Initialize indices vector to [0,1,2,..]
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> iter(0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> indices(N);
    thrust::copy(iter, iter + indices.size(), indices.begin());

    // --- First, sort the keys and indices by the keys
    thrust::sort_by_key(d_code.begin(), d_code.end(), indices.begin());

    // Now reorder the ID arrays using the sorted indices
    thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x.begin());
    thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), d_y.begin(), d_y.begin());
    thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), d_z.begin(), d_z.begin());
#endif

    printf("Timing GPU = %f\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

#ifdef VERBOSE
    h_code = d_code;
    h_x = d_x;
    h_y = d_y;

    printf("After\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) printf("code = %i; x = %f; y = %f\n", h_code[k], h_x[k], h_y[k]);
#endif
}
```

*Timing in the case of `2` arrays for `N = 1048576`*

```
zip_iterator  = 7.34ms
gather        = 4.27ms
```

*Timing in the case of `3` arrays for `N = 1048576`*

```
zip_iterator  = 9.64ms
gather        = 4.22ms
```

Tests performed on an NVIDIA GTX 960 card.

Comment: The above example looks incorrect. Gather operation is not supported inplace based on a question posted by @JackOLantern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560237/can-thrustgather-be-used-in-place?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: However I tested this and it seems to give the right answers. Can you please confirm if the gather operation supports inplace?

Answer (score 2):

I would use zip_iterator to perform one sort_by_key on both indice vectors at the same time.

This would look like this:

```
    typedef typename thrust::tuple<thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator, thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator> IteratorTuple;
    typedef typename thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> ZipIterator;   

    // here I suppose your 3 arrays are pointed to by device_ptr as suggested by @harrism
    thrust::device_vector<float> key(pKey, pKey + numElements);
    thrust::device_vector<int> val0(pVal0, pVal0 + numElements);
    thrust::device_vector<int> val1(pVal1, pVal1 + numElements);

    ZipIterator iterBegin(thrust::make_tuple(val0.begin(), val1.begin()));  
    thrust::sort_by_key(key.begin(), key.end(), iterBegin);
```