# Can thrust::gather be used "in-place"?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Consider the following code:

```
#include <time.h>       // --- time
#include <stdlib.h>     // --- srand, rand
#include<fstream>

#include <thrust\host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\sort.h>
#include <thrust\iterator\zip_iterator.h>

#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 16384;

    std::ifstream h_indices_File, h_x_File;
    h_indices_File.open("h_indices.txt");
    h_x_File.open("h_x.txt");

    std::ofstream h_x_result_File;
    h_x_result_File.open("h_x_result.txt");

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_indices(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_x(N);
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_sorted(N);

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        h_indices_File >> h_indices[k];
        h_x_File >> h_x[k];
    }

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices(h_indices);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_x(h_x);

    thrust::gather(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x.begin());
    h_x = d_x;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) h_x_result_File << h_x[k] << "\n";

    //thrust::device_vector<double> d_x_sorted(N);
    //thrust::gather(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x_sorted.begin());
    //h_x = d_x_sorted;
    //for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) h_x_result_File << h_x[k] << "\n";

}
```

The code loads from file an array of indices `h_indices.txt` and a `double` array `h_x.txt`. Then, it transfers those arrays to the GPU to `d_indices` and `d_x` and uses `thrust::gather` to achieve Matlab's equivalent

```
d_x(d_indices)
```

The two txt files can be downloaded from [h_indices.txt](http://pastebin.com/8Ui7RJes) and [h_x.txt](http://pastebin.com/3sTZkauq). The code creates an output result file `h_x_result.txt`.

If I use the "in-place" version of `thrust::gather` (the last uncommented three lines of the code), then I obtain that the result is different from `d_x(d_indices)`, while if I use the not "in-place" version (the last commented three lines of the code), then the result is correct.

In Matlab, I'm using

```
load h_indices.txt; load h_x.txt; load h_x_result.txt
plot(h_x(h_indices + 1)); hold on; plot(h_x_result, 'r'); hold off
```

The "in-place" case returns the following comparison
[image]

On the other side, the "in-place" case returns
[image]

I'm using Windows 10, CUDA 8.0, Visual Studio 2013, compiling in Release Mode and running on an NVIDIA GTX 960 cc. 5.2.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it did

Comment: I suspect that it cannot be used "in place", and I believe this is probably expected (i.e. UB), however, I haven't analyzed the thrust code to develop a conclusive argument, so as to be able to answer such a question.  (However your test code seems like a reasonable enough proof-point.)  As a service to the community, it might  be useful to file a thrust issue to request an augmentation of the existing restriction in the documentation against an overlap of output with map, with an additional restriction against the overlap of output with input.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you, Robert. Where should I file the thrust issue? [Here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues)?

Comment: @JackOLantern: This should not be an issue. Doing gather in-place means running into many caching issues; it's just not a good idea in any case I can think of. I mean, you could hide the out-of-place'ness under the hood and use a small(ish) out-of-place buffer than gets copied into place after it's been gathered into - but thrust doesn't offer that functionality.

Comment: @JackOLantern yes [there](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues)

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have requested an augmentation of the documentation  of `thrust::gather`, see this [issue](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/876). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrust `gather` can't be used in place.

But I would go as far as to suggest that no "naïve" gather operation can be safely performed in-place, and that the Matlab snippet you presented as in-place (presumably `d_x = d_x(d_indices)`) *isn't* an in-place operation at all.